# casperJS: how to access web site using facebook authentication?

Tags: facebook, authentication, casperjs

i would use casperjs in order to crawl web site pages.
Before this, i must login to the web site. Because web site allow to login using "facebook account", i would like simulate this using casperjs.
I wasn't able to find a sample.

Could any one help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//code to setup casper instance
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: "debug",
  waitTimeout: 7000,
  resourceTimeout: 10000,
  viewportSize: {
    width: 1024,
    height: 768
  },
  pageSettings: {
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    loadImages: true,
    loadPlugins: true
  }
});
//varibles required
var url = "https://www.facebook.com";
var utils = require('utils');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
//comamd line varibles
var user = casper.cli.args[0];
var pass = casper.cli.args[1];
// first step is to open the online resource
casper.start(url, function(response) {
  console.log(url + ' is opened');
});

// code to login to your facebook account
casper.then(function () {
  this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="email"]'),user);
  this.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="pass"]'),pass);
  this.click(x('//*[@id="u_0_q"]'));
});

//run the script
casper.run(function() {
  this.then(function () {
    //take a screenshot of login
    this.capture('facebook_screenshot.png');
    this.exit();
  });
});
```

The following code will log into Facebook if you could specify the website your scraping I'd be happy to write the additional code necessary to get to the Facebook login page